# Eliminate Duplicate Values with different id but same text

Tags: java, sql

i'm currently working on a software which displays the text values of a table in a combobox.The software have already a logic, which write the SQL commands with help of a MappingRessource.properties. For this you need the id and the text value. The problem is that, there are duplicate text values with different ids. Can someone explain me, how i can get only one of the duplicate values in my combobox?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLoTF.png)

```
SELECT DISTINCT id as id, description as text FROM engine WHERE description IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can you post your desired result?

Comment: What combo box? Why you need the id and which id should be used for the duplicate text values?

Answer (score 1):

When the value of the id is not important you can use

```
SELECT min(id) as id, description as text FROM engine group by description WHERE description IS NOT NULL
```